# Typescript returning error Argument of type is not assignable but it seems like it is confusing one function for another

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to make a global store hook with typescript. I keep getting the following error that I don't understand.

```
Argument of type '30' is not assignable to parameter of type '((store: any) => any) | undefined'.
```

The thing I don't understand is why I am getting the type `((store: any) => any) | undefined` on the dispatch function. It should be type `action: any` because that is what I am passing into the dispatch function. Type `((store: any) => any) | undefined` is used in the useStore function and should not be showing up as the dispatch functions argument.

How can I fix this?

Here is a codesandbox [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-support-global-store-hook-fdokk8)

Here is the App.js code:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import createStore from "./createStore";

const [useCount, setCount] = createStore(0);

function Counter() {
  const count = useCount();

  useEffect(() => {
    // here 30 is underlined with an error and I don't know why.
    setCount(30);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Count: {count}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setCount((count: number) => count + 1)}>+</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCount((count: number) => count - 1)}>-</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Counter />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the createStore.js code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const isFn = (fn: () => any) => typeof fn === "function";

const createStore = (initialStore: any) => {
  let store = initialStore;
  const listeners = new Set<any>();

  const getStore = () => store;

  const dispatch = (action: any) => {
    store = isFn(action) ? action(store) : action;

    listeners.forEach(({ updater }) => {
      updater(() => store);
    });
  };

  const useStore = (mapState = (store: any): any => store) => {
    const [, updater] = useState();
    const state = mapState(store);

    useEffect(() => {
      const listener = {
        state,
        mapState,
        updater
      };
      listeners.add(listener);
      return () => {
        listeners.delete(listener);
      };
    }, [state, mapState]);

    return state;
  };

  return [useStore, dispatch, getStore];
};

export default createStore;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your biggest issue here is that you are specifying the type `any` everywhere, which defeats the point of typescript and won't help you learn.

You need to set the return type on the function as typescript is inferring its type from the first value you are returning in the tuple.

If you tell typescript what to expect it won't infer anything.

You can define a tuple in the same shape as you want the return:

```js
type storeReturn = [((store: any) => any) | undefined, (action: any) => {}, () => {}];
```

Then when you define the function you specify the return type

```js
const createStore = (initialStore: any): storeReturn => { 
  // your code 
}
```

Doing this in your sandbox got the correct result for me. Typescript has incredible [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/) and I encourage you to give it a go. A good practice for me was to set strict rules in tsconfig to not allow the use of `any` like this.

Comment: The use of any everywhere is just to get up and running and then I was going to specify things later. I think using any is going to be a must here because the store can literally be set to anything.  Even if you look at something like redux then you will see `export interface Store<S = any,>` so even they use any for the store value. If there were no use cases for any then it would not be a feature in typescript. Your answer did fix the problem but I still don't know why I am getting the error on the dispatch function with the useState functions type being specified.

Comment: @user3331344 Because you didnt specify the return, Typescript inferred that the function return type would be an array of items all with the same type `[(store: any) => any) | undefined]`. You could circumvent this by putting a return type of `any` or by doing what I showed, then typescript wont infer anything.